# Performance for searching through 100 million records

Tags: mysql, regex, performance, search, dns

I am doing PHP and have 11 million domains in text files loaded into an array and then I search through them using regex.

To do this I need to jack up memory limit to 2gigs and then it takes like 10 seconds to process.  I will soon have 100 million domains and plan on moving to a database solution, but still, how do you get good performance when searching through a list of 100 million domains?

I search using regex like this:

```
$domains = preg_grep("/store\./", $array);

foreach($domains as $domain) {echo $domain;}
```

Comment: 11 million domains right now and 100 million in future? That cries for a database!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a search engine like lucene:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

It is meant for this very purpose.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing me to Lucene.  Do you have an opinion on Sphinx vs ElasticSearch vs Lucene?

Comment: Sorry must admit that i only know about lucene, so i cant comment on that

Answer (score 2):

Regex is probably the slowest way to search something. You may benefit from MongoDB if you are dealing with such large volumes of data.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "search". Regex? Scan parts of strings? Databases wond help - indices are of no help for full partial matches.

OTOH for real matching (especially if you store like the domain name separate from the top level part)... I would expect single digit ms on any decent hardware.

Regex - better load the file into memory ONCE and keep it there. Yes, needs 2 gig - who cares. 64 gigabyte servers are cheap ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you know what the domain begins with, this might be of interest. You could separate your text files out into "begins with" files. A domain can start with 36 different characters (that's a-z plus 0-9). Have 36 different files, and keep them maintained that way.

Since your example begins with 's', you would run that on the 's' file, and find that the query is much quicker - it has less to search through.

If you will always know the first N characters of your search (i.e. there is no wildcard at the front) you can achieve exponentially better results by splitting files up into groups. Since subsequent characters may include a hyphen, your number of files would be no more than 36 * (37 ^ (N - 1)), where N > 1... which is still quite a lot!

Comment: I want to do different kind of searches, all domains that have 4 characters, domains that end with a word, etc.

Comment: Np. I'd go with @khebbie's solution, then.