# mysql performance with 100 million+ records

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table with two columns, like this:

```
col_A   mediumint(8)        UNSIGNED
col_B   int(10)         UNSIGNED
```

indexed on both columns. expecting around 300million+ records or so. the queries for read and write will be no more than 10/per second.

I want to know how slow it can get on of-the-shelf hardware, (sata hdd with around 16GB RAM, linux server)

I read the similar question and answer to it in here: [performance for searching through 100 million records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862308/performance-for-searching-through-100-million-records)
but i am already using mysql for lot of other tables (none as big).

Comment: If you have a spinny disk, maybe. If you have an SSD, probably. To find out for sure *test on your hardware under your anticipated read and write load conditions* by simulating and benchmarking. Generating that much test data won't take long. Honestly just about anything this side of a Raspberry Pi can handle 10 TPS, so you're probably fine.

Comment: Too broad for SO. Not a programming question. IMHO.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  "indexed on both columns" could mean `INDEX(A,B)` or `INDEX(B,A)` or `INDEX(A), INDEX(B)`.

Comment: Please provide the `SELECTs`.  `SELECT * FROM t` may take minutes; `SELECT B FROM t WHERE A=1234` will take only milliseconds if `A` is indexed.

Comment: Thanks tadman . @Rick, all queries will be like: SELECT B FROM t WHERE A=1234  Also, indexes are index(a,b) and index(b,a). thanks all for response.

Comment: @rajeev  Please provide A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; B) SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; C) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (remainder of your query);  Why do I ask for this?  To verify the data IS for ENGINE innodb, to verify you have a PRIMARY KEY, to avoid wasting space and CPU when there is NO primary key.  To view cardinality of your indexes.  To see how the optimizer decided to process you query.

Answer (score 0):

Given `INDEX(A,B)`, you can probably have multiple connections doing `SELECT B FROM t WHERE A=...` at a combined rate of more than 1000/second, even on HDD.

That table is only a few GB, and if you set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 11G (for 16GB of RAM), you have room to grow (without swapping).